# Detached entity passed to persist - Hibernate + JavaFX

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, javafx

i'm newbie in Hibernate and i need help.

I have table called **Kasa** with 3 attributes - id, address and account_id. In my table i have 12 rows.
I want to map this using Hibernate and add new one using Java so I did this:

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name = "kasa")
    public class Kasa {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "incrementor")
        @GenericGenerator(name = "incrementor", strategy = "increment")
        @Column(name = "ID_KASA")
        private  int id;

        @Column(name = "ADRES")
        private String adres;

        @Column(name = "ID_KONTO")
        private  int id_konta;
     }
```

I have also getters and setters but no need to copy that.

Now i would like to add new row to my db, like this:

```
EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = 
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("org.hibernate.jpa");

        Kasa kasa = new Kasa();

        kasa.setId(1);
        kasa.setAdres("Kolorowaa");
        kasa.setId_konta(2);

        EntityManager entityManager = 
        entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.persist(kasa);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
```

And I get error like this:
**javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: model.beans.Kasa**

It is pointing on this line: **entityManager.persist(kasa);**

I think the problem can be with ID of my 'Kasa' class because it is generated automatically.

For my configuration i am using persistence.xml file - connection with db works fine. Pls help :)

Comment: doesn't seem to be related to javafx, or how is it?

Comment: i am building javafx app with hibernate :)

Comment: yeah sure, but your problem is unrelated to javafx, right?

Comment: no, it s not related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the ID! If you do that, JPA things kasa is already in the database.

Database-id must be set by JPA. There for you have to define some strategy how the
key schould be calculated. That's what all theses... @Generate... tags do.

Comment: Yes but when i delete line where i set ID i get another error: Transaction not successfully started in this line :  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

Comment: When you write to the database use entityManager.getTransaction().begin()

Your complete code should look like:


EntityManager entityManager =  entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

>>>>        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();   <<<<<

        entityManager.persist(kasa);

        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();


        entityManagerFactory.close();